# Is it possible to make an input value as macro in cpp?

Tags: c++, input, macros, global

In C++, is it possible to take an input value form the user and then declare it as a macro in real-time?

Comment: No you can not do that. macros no longer exist after the preprocessor processes them (before the code is compiled). Also in `c++` you should limit your usage of macros anyways.

Comment: What would be the point? What the [real goal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Answer (score 0):

No you can not do that. Macros no longer exist after the preprocessor processes them which is before the code is compiled. Also in c++ you should limit your usage of macros anyways. There are better type safe methods in modern `c++` depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Macros get pre-processed into your code somewhat like copy and pasting the macro definition wherever you use it. This is the first step that your compiler does. Once your program gets pre-processed, compilation and linking follow.

If you had something like this:

```
#define WIDTH 1920
#define HEIGHT 1080

Window window(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
...
int windowWidth = WIDTH;
int windowHeight = HEIGHT;
```

It would get process into this:

```
Window window(1920, 1080);
...
int windowWidth = 1920;
int windowHeight = 1080;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This could make an interesting experiment.

1. The programmer writes code that will define a macro at runtime.
2. The pre-processor handles (among other things) all of the macros in the code.
3. The compiler and linker join forces to convert the pre-processed (and macro-free) code into an executable.
4. The (source-code-free) executable is launched (maybe on a different computer!).
5. The executable receives a macro definition from the user.
6. The executable opens a time window, sending the macro back in time to step 2, when it can be handled.
7. In the altered history, the new macro causes compilation to fail; no executable is created in step 3.
8. With no executable to run, steps 4-6 never occur, leading to a TIME PARADOX!
9. As the space-time continuum rips itself to shreds, the C++ Standards Committee holds an emergency meeting to make sure "time travel" is cleanly in the category of "Undefined Behavior".

:)